# How to convert a string to array, where string is in array form, the values inside string are in latex

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, latex

How to convert a string to an array, where the string is in array form, the values inside the string are in latex, array string can be nested any number of times.

```
"[[\\frac{234}{3243}],[34342]]" to [["\\frac{234}{3243}"],["34342"]]
```

Array string can be nested any number of times.

I can't use eval and JSON.parse, latex won't allow me to do that

```
const alphabetRegex = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;

const parseQuestionResponse = (userInput) => {
    let inputString = userInput.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
    return inputString
      .slice(1, -1)
      .split("],")
      .map(elem => {
            if (elem.length > 1) {
                elem = elem.slice(1, -1);
                userInput.match(alphabetRegex) == null ?
                    elem = elem.split(",") :
                    elem = [elem];
            }
            else elem = [""];
            return elem;
      });
  };
```

I tried this some of the cases it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex split with Positive Lookbehind

https://regex101.com/r/biX5JV/1

```js
const alphabetRegex = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;

const parseQuestionResponse = (userInput) => {
  return userInput
    .slice(1, -1)
    .split(/(?<=]),/)
    .map(elem => {
      if (elem.length > 1) {
        elem = elem.slice(1, -1);
        userInput.match(alphabetRegex) == null ?
          elem = elem.split(",") :
          elem = [elem];
      } else elem = [""];
      return elem;
    });
};

console.log(parseQuestionResponse('[[\\frac{234}{3243}],[34342]]'))
console.log(parseQuestionResponse('[[\\frac{23}{\\frac{23}{23}}],[23243]]'))
```

Comment: '[[\\frac{23}{\\frac{23}{23}}],[23243]]' for this input is giving wrong converting // to /

Comment: @MayankSharma your input doesn't have `//`. check the answer it's working fine.

Comment: Tried this on console instead of \\ backward i am getting \

Comment: @MayankSharma Is the result here correct? How can I help you with without any words except `wrong` and `not getting` :(

Comment: @MayankSharma If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left and upvote it by clicking on the UP triangle ▲.